# Linux passwd User permission change

Tags: linux, command

When I look at

```
usr/bin/
```

directory, I saw the command line with passwd

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 30768 2012-02-22 20:48 /usr/bin/passwd
```

and It allows to change to get root's authority. with s.

I was wonder that only root possibly can change the other user's passwd with

```
passwd   user
```

I want to find the location of this command and look it up.

is this command also part of the usr/bin/ directory? or its something else

the what I want to do is.

I log in

```
user1
```

and type

```
[user1] passwd user2
```

of course It's blocked in some how. but I want to know more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix (and Linux) has the concept of *real* user and *effective* user.  A setuid program such as `/usr/bin/passwd` will set the effective user to the owner of the file; in this case it sets the effective user to `root`.

Now what a program does with these elevated permissions is up to the program itself.

In the case of the `passwd` program, if you pass a username then it will check to see if the *real* user is root; it if is then it succeeds, otherwise it returns an error.

So the `root` user can run `/usr/bin/password user2` and this will work, but if `user` runs the same command then it fails.   There's just the one program, but the way it works changes depending on the user that runs it.

Answer (score 2):

The `passwd` binary is suid because it needs root permission to modify the `/etc/shadow` file. It will not allow an unprivileged user to modify a different user's password. It will allow `root` to modify any user's password, but that is not why it is suid.

Comment: yes, I understood. I was played around with passwd. I knew It get the root permissions to modify it. My question is where does "passwd user" command  file  located?

Comment: `which passwd` will tell you where the binary is, but you've already found it, it's at /usr/bin/passwd`